# MissingPluginException for quick_actions plugin in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, quickaction, flutter-release

I recently added quick_actions plugin works fine in debug mode but shows a blank screen in release mode.

**Found these issues in the log.**

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLaunchAction on channel plugins.flutter.io/quick_actions)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      QuickActions.initialize (package:quick_actions/quick_actions.dart:68)

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setShortcutItems on channel plugins.flutter.io/quick_actions)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the same issue for google_fonts package. As of now to remove this issue from the release mode I added `shrinkResources false` in the app level `build.grade` file of android folder. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Brooooo! works like charm. Thanks :)

Will edit your answer to add more information that I had to search.