# Google sign-in doesn't work after releasing apk from flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

The app in debug mode was working fine and everything is good. after releasing apk, Google sign-in doesn't work. I tried all the possible solutions, I checked for the SHA1 key and all is good and added everything in the Gradle. nothing is missing but it still, gives me an error.

[image]

here are the Gradle files
[image: here are the Gradle files]
[image]

and when I use it in debug mode, it works again like flutter run but if I run fluter install and use the installed apk it doesn't work and it gives this error

here is the function

[image: here is the function]

here is how I call it
[image: here is how I call it]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, in my case with firebase token, this post helped.
[MissingPluginException for quick_actions plugin in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573481/missingpluginexception-for-quick-actions-plugin-in-release-mode/65574155)

Quote from the accepted answer:

> As of now to remove this issue from the release mode I added `shrinkResources false` in the app level `build.grade file` of android folder.